# how do I call json api data online javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to create a table and search filter, the data is taken from here 
https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json. Can anyone give an example of how to retrieve data through json api and how to create a filter search?

Comment: What's your question?  How to use the Fetch API?

Comment: yes fetch api how to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap jQuery example will help with filtering.

> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_filters.asp

In order to access the API, you need to create an AJAX (XHR, Http Requester, etc...) call to retrieve the data. If you use jQuery , this is as easy as:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json', // Expecting JSON
  url: 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json', // Data endpoint
  cache: true, // Cache the request for testing purposes
  success: function(data) {
    populateTable(data.results); // On success, access the data
  }
});
```

As for populating the table, you need to get the fields from one of the data items in the results and sort them. You can also ignore some of the fields as seen below.

```
$('#myTable')
  .append($('<thead>')
    .append($('<tr>')
      .append(fields.map(field => $('<th>').addClass('text-center').text(field)))))
  .append($('<tbody>')
    .append(data.map(result => $('<tr>')
      .append(fields.map(field => $('<td>').text(result[field]))))));
```

**Update:** If you want a loading mask, you need to create a div with absolute positioning inside the container of the results. When requesting the data, show the mask. After receiving the response, hide it.

```html
<div class="loadable">
  <div class="loading-mask"></div>
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped"></table>
</div>
```

```css
.loadable {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.loadable > .loading-mask,
.loadable > table {
  position: absolute;
}
```

### Demo

```js
let ignoreFields = [ 'created', 'edited', 'films', 'residents', 'url' ],
    sortField    = 'name';

$(function() {
  $('.loading-mask').show(); // Show mask before request
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      populateTable(data.results);
      $('.loading-mask').hide(); // Hide mask after response
    },
    failure: function(data) {
      $('.loading-mask').hide(); // Hide mask after response
    }
  });
  $('#myInput').on('keyup', onFilter);
});

function populateTable(data) {
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a[sortField].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[sortField].toLowerCase());
  });

  var fields = Object.keys(data[0]).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === sortField) return -1;
    if (b === sortField) return 1;
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  }).filter(x => ignoreFields.indexOf(x) === -1);

  $('#myTable')
    .append($('<thead>')
      .append($('<tr>')
        .append(fields.map(field => $('<th>').addClass('text-center').text(field)))))
    .append($('<tbody>')
      .append(data.map(result => $('<tr>')
        .append(fields.map(field => $('<td>').text(result[field]))))));
}

function onFilter(e) {
  let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('#myTable tbody tr').filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });
}
```

```css
.loadable {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.loadable > .loading-mask,
.loadable > table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px; /* Same as its parent */
}

.loading-mask {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lW8P6HP.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#myInput {
  margin-bottom: 0.667em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable Table</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <div class="loadable">
    <div class="loading-mask"></div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped"></table>
  </div>
  <p>Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how to add loading https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp, when data is being retrieved

Comment: @putrairawan Added a loading mask, its an easy concept. All you have to do is show it before the request is made and hide if after receiving a response.

Comment: How to ? I ask brother, because I just learned javascript

Comment: thank you very much brother

Comment: @putrairawan I actually messed up the `<thead>`, I forgot to assign it a `<tr>`. I updated the response e.g. `$('#myTable tbody tr').filter`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Datatables` library with `Ajax sourced data` or `Server-side processing` for requirement create table and search, filter data from API.

There are reference links with sample javascript code

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Update:

I added demo with script and HTML for Datatables. You can set `dataSrc property` to `results property` in returned object `dataSrc: 'results'`

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json',
        dataSrc: 'results'
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "name" }, 
      { data: "climate" }, 
      { data: "diameter" },
      { data: "gravity" },
      {data: "orbital_period"},
      {data: "population"}
    ]
})
```

[image]

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json',
        dataSrc: 'results'
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "name" }, 
      { data: "climate" }, 
      { data: "diameter" },
      { data: "gravity" },
      {data: "orbital_period"},
      {data: "population"}
    ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>climate</th>
                <th>diameter</th>
                <th>gravity</th>
                <th>orbital_period</th>
                <th>population</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>climate</th>
                <th>diameter</th>
                <th>gravity</th>
                <th>orbital_period</th>
                 <th>population</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: how to retrieve this data https://swapi.co/api/planets/?format=json

Comment: my side cant access your link, you need ensure it return a JSON object

Comment: I updated demo use datatables

Comment: Thnk you brother